# Need help simplifying trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

$\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}+\csc x \sin x$

Please Help I have a difficult time with trigonometry and can't seem to simplify this one problem.

Comment: Do you know what $\csc X$ means?

Comment: $\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} = (\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} )^2 = $?

Answer (score 2):

One very important thing to know is: $\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1$.
Also, you need the definition of $\csc$. It is $\csc x = \frac{1}{\sin x}$.
Pluggin this into your expression, we have: $$\frac{1 - \sin^2 x}{\sin^2 x} + \frac{1}{\sin x}\sin x$$

Can you go on from here?